# How to link one GUI window to another

Tags: python, tkinter

I have two separate Python codes and I want that if I click a button on the first GUI then a new GUI window should open and taken in the input in the entry field.

I have been able to successfully open a new GUI window after clicking the button on the first GUI, but the second window does not take in my input. Could someone please check my code and tell me why my second GUI is not taking and input. I am pasting a part of my two python codes to keep it concise.

When I click button YES in the first code, a new Python GUI window opens, but when I enter the values in the entry field and press Pipe 1 FWD Button, the code does not take this input.

First and Second Codes:

```
import sys
from Tkinter import *
import Prog2 as ofnew
def askOffsets():
    print 'Correct till here'
    of = ofnew.AddOffset()
mGui = Tk()
mGui.geometry('1000x600+150+100')
buttonYesOffsets = Button(text = 'YES', command = askOffsets)
buttonYesOffsets.place(x = 300, y = 350)
mGui.mainloop()
```

---

```
import sys
from Tkinter import *
import time, datetime
from numpy import arange

class AddOffset():

    def getOffsetsPipe1FWD(self):
        print 'Correct'
        temp1 = self.StartFreqOffsets.get()
        print temp1

    def __init__(self):
        self.mOffsets = Tk()
        self.mOffsets.geometry('1000x600+100+100')
        self.mOffsets.title('Enter the Offsets')
        self.StartFreqOffsets = DoubleVar()
        self.StartFreqOffsets.set(1)
        labelenterStartFreqOffsets = Label(self.mOffsets, text = 'Enter the Start Frequency (in MHz):')
        labelenterStartFreqOffsets.place(x = 0, y = 50)
        self.entryStartFreqOffsets = Entry(self.mOffsets, textvariable = self.StartFreqOffsets).place(x = 250, y = 50)

        buttonPipe1FWD = Button(self.mOffsets, text = 'Pipe 1 FWD', command = self.getOffsetsPipe1FWD)
        buttonPipe1FWD.place(x = 30, y = 300)
        self.mOffsets.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Within a single Tkinter application, you should only ever create a single instance of `Tk`, and you should only ever call `mainloop` exactly once. In your case, each file is creating its own instance of `Tk`.

If you want multiple windows, every window but the root window needs to be an instance of `Toplevel`.

Comment: Yes, I think that in general for other windows we should use instances of the `Toplevel` widget, but this is not always the case, at least this is what I have read once, I think in the effbot.org website. We know that for each `Tk` instance there's an associated Tcl interpreter running in the background (if I am not wrong), so in case of multiple Tk instances we have multiple Tcl interpreters running in the background. So, if this is correct, is there any particular situation where having more than one Tcl interpreter running in the background would be useful?

Answer (score 0):

You program prints the contents of the Entry widget correctly for multiple new windows when a Toplevel is used.  Code modified to come from one file instead of two

```
from Tkinter import *
##import Prog2 as ofnew
import sys
##from Tkinter import *
import time, datetime
##from numpy import arange

class AddOffset():

    def getOffsetsPipe1FWD(self):
        print 'Correct'
        temp1 = self.StartFreqOffsets.get()
        print temp1

    def __init__(self, top):
        self.mOffsets = Toplevel(top)
        ## all new windows will be at the same location
        ## (on top of each other)
        self.mOffsets.geometry('1000x600+100+100')
        self.mOffsets.title('Enter the Offsets')
        self.StartFreqOffsets = DoubleVar()
        self.StartFreqOffsets.set(1)
        labelenterStartFreqOffsets = Label(self.mOffsets, text = 'Enter the Start Frequency (in MHz):')
        labelenterStartFreqOffsets.place(x = 0, y = 50)
        Entry(self.mOffsets, textvariable = self.StartFreqOffsets).place(x = 250, y = 50)

        buttonPipe1FWD = Button(self.mOffsets, text = 'Pipe 1 FWD',
                                command = self.getOffsetsPipe1FWD)
        buttonPipe1FWD.place(x = 30, y = 300)

def askOffsets():
    print 'Correct till here'
    of = AddOffset(mGui)

mGui = Tk()
mGui.geometry('1000x600+150+100')
buttonYesOffsets = Button(text = 'YES', command = askOffsets)
buttonYesOffsets.place(x = 300, y = 350)
mGui.mainloop()
```